# Create a location-based rotating globe similar to Google Earth using C# and Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently in the process of developing an iOS app involving a touch-enabled rotating globe. I have already found past links for this such as: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/255118/rotating-an-object-with-touch.html

**The question is:**
Is possible to make this object location-oriented? I plan to create a cel-shaded globe with different points on the object related to specific locations.

**Edit:** These locations are not GPS oriented, but just meaning points on an object (globe) represented by objects (tree).

Here is an example I created for a class using Dreamweaver many years ago that would look similar, but touch-oriented instead of using 'West' and 'East' buttons located in the top left of the video: https://youtu.be/UZACQtnQfkA

***Sorry the example is in video form, I don't have the code available for comparison at the moment.***

Comment: _"Is possible to make this object location-oriented?"_ - anything is possible. [Unity has location services](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LocationService.Start.html). What you do with the data that returns is up to you.

Comment: This seems to be more based on the user's location. Maybe my question was a little broad. I meant "location-based" as in the globe would just have different points on it represented by another object (ex: a 3D tree representing a location) No GPS involved necessarily.

Comment: can you emphasize on "location-oriented"?

Comment: @oxy i am looking for same globe but interactive glob like google earth in unity3d. Any solution found? please share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is being naive and you seem to lack knowledge in Unity3D. I suggest you to go through their [official tutorials](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) and get and idea. Then ask if you have any specific questions on issues you're encountering.

You can follow some tutorials to create such scene by [PlannetaryTerrain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yOC0EKIpNRw). You can see some [efforts on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wx7ociYsIXg) as well.

Apart from that creating terrains would be a plus. Follow the [tutorial by Kostiantyn](http://kostiantyn-dvornik.blogspot.com/2014/02/huge-amazing-unity-terrain-tutorial.html). Also Follow the Faux gravity [tutorial by Sebastian](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHeQ8Hr92P4)

Comment: Thank you for your response! While it was a general question, I see no harm in asking whether it is possible considering my lack of experience in Unity3D. I will follow those steps.

Comment: Usually StackOverflow community believe that "Is it possible?", "What is better?" type of questions to be found out through googling! This is better to be used for specific questions, like "The touch input is not working properly" ;)